# Dynamic function parameter names

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to dynamically generate function parameter names?

```js
type Foo<ParamName extends string> = (`arg${Capitalize<ParamName>}`: number)=>void

type X = Foo<'num'> // should be (argNum: number)=>void
```

Related: can one define a tuple such that:

```js
type Bar<ParamName extends string> = [`arg${Capitalize<ParamName>}`: number]

type Y = Bar<'num'> // should be [argNum: number]
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPABQIYCdUFsBy3oQAewEAdgCYDOUlw6AlqQOYB8UAvFABQAGGTAEgDeAYVRh6wVABt6ALwgoM2PFggsAvjwBcUUgFcsAIwjoAlOxYA3OPXIAoe6EhQAGh1gJEAcgNZvbAD0gTQAFnD60uRQJtz8OIa6fibmljZ2js7QAEIYSpi4+FBEJBTUtAzMbJwA2nzogqLikjLyimgFqupaSYYpALqZ4NAAmh656D5+AVDBYRFRMdA18Yl6fab9QA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do so, argument name is just a label, it has no effect on type condition and is not subject to any computation on types.

For example in

```
type A = (a: string)=>void
type B = (b: string)=>void
```

types `A` and `B` are semantically equivalent, so you can't for example extract `'a'` from `A` using something like

```
A extends (infer name: string) => void ? name : never
```

or introduce the argument name as a string like what you are trying to accomplish or like this:

```
type A = ('a': string) => void
```

Argument names can't be treated as types.